# Converting VB6 Type to C# struct

Tags: c#, vb6, interop, vb6-migration

```
Public Type WIN32_FIND_DATA
    dwFileAttributes As Long
    ftCreationTime As FILETIME
    ftLastAccessTime As FILETIME
    ftLastWriteTime As FILETIME
    nFileSizeHigh As Long
    nFileSizeLow As Long
    dwReserved0 As Long
    dwReserved1 As Long
    cFileName As String * MAX_PATH
    cAlternate As String * 14
End Type
```

This is my original **VB6** code and the converted **C#** code is

```
public struct WIN32_FIND_DATA
{
    long dwFileAttributes;
    FILETIME ftLastAccessTime;
    FILETIME ftLastWriteTime;
    long nFileSizeHigh;
    long nFileSizeLow;
    long dwReserved0;
    long dwReserved1;
    cFileName As String * max_path;
    cAlternate As String * 14
}
```

How to convert `cFileName As String * max_path` into C#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you want to *marshal* this `struct` (e.g. when calling `FindFirstFileEx`, `FindNextFile` API functions); if it's your case

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

... 

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct WIN32_FIND_DATA
{
    public uint dwFileAttributes;
    public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ftCreationTime;
    public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ftLastAccessTime;
    public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ftLastWriteTime;
    public uint nFileSizeHigh;
    public uint nFileSizeLow;
    public uint dwReserved0;
    public uint dwReserved1;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = MAX_PATH)] // MAX_PATH = 260
    public string cFileName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 14)]
    public string cAlternateFileName;
}
```

see original [WIN32_FIND_DATA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-_win32_find_dataa) declaration for details

Comment: @Mohan Also in case you didn't know, the .NET framework provides easier and more straight-forward ways to search for files. You might want to look into these methods: [`Directory.EnumerateFiles()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles) and [`Directory.EnumerateDirectories()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratedirectories). They both allow you to search for files/folders in a directory with the option to search in the sub-directories as wel.